# Getting push notification details on app launch

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, appdelegate

Is there any way to get information from push notification when app is launched (from killed state) by tapping its icon, and PUSH IS NOT BEING TAPPED?

Comment: Did you try using `launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]` in your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method?

Comment: Sure! Unfortunately `launchOptions != nil` only when user TAPS the push

Comment: Elena : You can not get push notification with out PUSH TAPPED. Other way can get same info from service API on launch :)

Comment: @kaushal: Thanks a lot, I guessed so, just wanted to exclude any phantom possibility before turning to the back-end guy =)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that you could handle the notification once it's received (you set the `content-available` flag so your code can be run), store a flag on UserDefaults along with the push information, and once the app is opened you could use these informations.

For more information on "silent" push notifications check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW6)

Comment: Actually the problem isn't with "silent" push - this kind I can already handle. The problem is with push received to "killed" app and starting it from icon. But it seems that there's no other way than to get it with API

Answer (score 0):

You can't get informations from a notification in notification center without the user tapping it.

However, if you are trying to implement invisible notifications, that's possible, but the app won't launch foreground.

Comment: This is not exactly true. I can get always get notification info when the app is running or in background no matter if user taps on notification or not. The only situation that it is impossible to read notification info is when the app is killed and user launches it from icon, not from push notification.